# How to change Blender's default UV editing display

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm new to blender but have experience with 3DS Max.

Inside blender when you enter the UV editor, only the faces that are currently selected in Edit mode appear on the UV grid. What I would like is to have all the faces of the object displayed on the UV grid without the need to select each individual face. And if possible also have what I currently have selected in the UV Grid appear in the edit mode so I can see what I'm editing easier. Are there preferences, settings or a plug-in that might help me or am I stuck with Blenders default UV Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *UV Sync Selection* button should do what you want:

[image]

Comment: You are a wonderful human being thank you for this. it is exactly what I wanted.